# Installing ubuntu partitions problem

Tags: partitioning

I installed ubuntu 13.10 by replace os(windows). Now ubuntu is with total memory space. So i can't install another os. how it is done?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**:You can't move,resize or delete a mounted partition using gparted.You installed ubuntu on a single disk,for resize that you must bootup gparted live-disk or ubuntu-live disk.If you had ubuntu live-disk,follow the below steps,

- Boot ubuntu live-disk,click on try ubuntu,then connect to the internet and openup the terminal.And run the below commands to install gparted

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gparted && sudo gparted
  ```
- Right-click on the partition(where ubuntu is installed) then select the option Resize/Move.Now reduce the size of how much space did you want for another Os.
- After resizing,an unallocated space was created just below to the Ubuntu partition.
- Now right-click on the unallocated space and click on the **New** option.From that Create ntfs partition for windows or ext4 partition for any linux distros.

Answer (score 0):

I would install your "other" OS first. Use that OS' setup to make a partition for it, leaving the portion of your disk you want to use for Ubuntu as 'unpartitioned free space'

Then install Ubuntu, into that free space.

Chances are your "other" OS will destroy GRUB on the MBR and you will not be able to boot into Ubuntu. By installing Ubuntu after that other OS, you will have a working GRUB, and GRUB will boot linux, windows, unix, etc